# Code duplication issue inside an if

Tags: c#-4.0, duplication

I have a code duplication that I want to avoid but I cannot create a method containing the code because there is a slight difference in a line inside an if. Here's what I mean :

Code 1 :

```
If case1 ()
{
    same code
    if()
    {
        same code 
        line1
    }
```

Code 2 :

```
If case2 ()
{
    same code
    if()
    {
        same code 
        line2
    }
```

Both codes are the same except one line (line1 and line2). Since the code is big I want to be be able to copy it inside a function for example. Do you have an idea how to this?

Thanks

Comment: Is line2 and line1 something you could pass from outside the function?

Comment: No it must be inside

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, you are looking for an `Action` or `Func`. That's a type that encapsulates executable code:

```
public int YourCommonMethod(int parameter, Func<int, int> calculate)
{
   // some common code

   if(calculationNeeded)
   {
      // some common code
      result = calculate(parameter);
   }

   // more common code
}
```

You could then call it with two different calculation methods:

```
int result = YourCommonMethod(5, i => i + 17);
```

OR

```
int result = YourCommonMethod(5, i => i / 48);
```

For just an action, you need less:

```
public int YourCommonMethod(int parameter, Action<int> doWork)
{
   // some common code

   if(calculationNeeded)
   {
      // some common code
      doWork(parameter);
   }

   // more common code
}
```

And you can call it like this:

```
int result = YourCommonMethod(5, Console.WriteLine);
```

OR

```
int result = YourCommonMethod(5, i => Console.WriteLine("Some string including {0}", i));
```

Comment: Thank you I didn't know that existed I'm going to try it.

Comment: Since my line is a method that returns nothing I used an Action. Can you help me out with the same implementation but with an Action. Thanks

Comment: @AnasB Added an action implementation. You can just use `Action` without the `<int>` if your method is not taking parameters either.

Answer (score 1):

You could split your code into multiple methods:

```
if (case1)
{
    subMethod1();
    if ()
    {
        subMethod2();
        line1;
    }       
}

if (case2)
{
    subMethod1();
    if ()
    {
        subMethod2();
        line2;
    }       
}
```

Comment: Yes I thought about this but there's still some duplication left because I would have to reuse both submethods multiple times since this part of code is used many times. I was seeking a solution that groups all the code except for the one line. I don't know if it's possible.